# DataFrame element-wise divide by sum of row inplace

Tags: python, pandas

I want every element divided by sum of row inplace,code below always go wrong.

pandas newbie, thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12).reshape(3,4),columns=list('abcd'))
df_row_sum = df.apply(lambda x: x.mean(),axis=1)
df / df_row_sum
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need `sum` or maybe `mean` per rows (`axis=1`) with division by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) :

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=12).reshape(3,4),columns=list('abcd'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  2  2  6  1
1  3  9  6  1
2  0  1  9  0

print (df.sum(axis=1))
0    11
1    19
2    10
dtype: int64

print (df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0))
          a         b         c         d
0  0.181818  0.181818  0.545455  0.090909
1  0.157895  0.473684  0.315789  0.052632
2  0.000000  0.100000  0.900000  0.000000
```

---

```
print (df.mean(axis=1))
0    2.75
1    4.75
2    2.50
dtype: float64

print (df.div(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0))
          a         b         c         d
0  0.727273  0.727273  2.181818  0.363636
1  0.631579  1.894737  1.263158  0.210526
2  0.000000  0.400000  3.600000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @jezrael's setup

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=12).reshape(3,4),columns=list('abcd'))
print (df)

   a  b  c  d
0  2  2  6  1
1  3  9  6  1
2  0  1  9  0
```

Use `numpy` and reconstruct a new dataframe

```
v = df.values
pd.DataFrame(
    v / v.sum(1, keepdims=True),
    df.index, df.columns
)

          a         b         c         d
0  0.181818  0.181818  0.545455  0.090909
1  0.157895  0.473684  0.315789  0.052632
2  0.000000  0.100000  0.900000  0.000000
```