# pandas dividing rows by its total

Tags: python, pandas, row, division

I have this df:

```
Name    num1  num2   num3  
A       1      2      3    
B       4      5      6    
C       7      8      9
```

My goal is to divide each row by the total.  This is what I came up with:

```
df.loc[:,"num1":"num3"] = df.loc[:,"num1":"num3"].div(df["total"], axis=0)
```

It works well.  However, if there are more "numx" columns added in after num3, I would have to manually update the code to "num1":"numx".  Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataFrame element-wise divide by sum of row inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241521/dataframe-element-wise-divide-by-sum-of-row-inplace)

Comment: do you want the column to be dynamically calculated?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound that would be the goal

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Why don't you create a function that recalculates the column and call it after every update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first select matching columns:

```
In [21]: cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^num\d+')]
```

then divide elements in those rows by their sum (calculated for each row):

```
In [22]: df[cols] = df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0)

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  Name      num1      num2   num3
0    A  0.166667  0.333333  0.500
1    B  0.266667  0.333333  0.400
2    C  0.291667  0.333333  0.375
```

Comment: Nice answer! How would this change if instead of num1, num2, num3 I just have 1,2,3?

Comment: @TylerNG, do you mean numbers or strings?

Comment: I converted 1,2,3 to strings

Comment: @TylerNG, then use `cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^\d+')]`

Comment: How would the code change if you use numbers instead of string?

Comment: @TylerNG, that's easy: `cols = df.columns[df.columns.astype(str).str.contains('^\d+')]`

Comment: you guys make coding looks so simple :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163359/discussion-between-maxu-and-tylerng).

Answer (score 2):

You need    `select_dtypes`

```
df.loc[:,df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns]=df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').div(df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').sum(1),0)

df
Out[66]: 
  Name      num1      num2   num3
0    A  0.166667  0.333333  0.500
1    B  0.266667  0.333333  0.400
2    C  0.291667  0.333333  0.375
```

Comment: could you please explain what is happening here?

Comment: @Wen I got TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences

Comment: @TylerNG ummm, seems like I am ok with the code , can you try it with you sample dataframe ?

Comment: @Wen I got it now :) Thank you as always!

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply function and apply the division on each row. It'll give same results.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x = x.div(x.sum()), axis=1)
```